# jquery accordion tab

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to have a jquery accordion tab to display different content to the top and to the bottom of the tab when clicked

if you check the following website

http://www.eset.com/us/#tab=fbus

You should see 2 tabs one for business and the other for home, when you select the business tab, the picture above the tab changes along with the content of the tab.

how can I do that in jQuery JavaScript?

I wonder if someone could help!

Thank you

Comment: there are lot of examples on web on how to use tabs. You can simply download jquery-ui library, and start with those examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty something like

html

```
<div class="fhome tabed">fhome Content 01 </div>
<div class="fbus tabed" style="display:none;">fbus Content 02 </div>
<ul id="Tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab=fhome">Tab 01 </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab=fbus">Tab 01 </a></li>
</ul>
<div class="fhome tabed">fhome Content 01 </div>
<div class="fbus tabed" style="display:none;">fbus Content 02 </div>
```

and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#Tabs li a').click(function(){
        $('.tabed').hide();
        var Shdiv = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1]
        $('div.'+Shdiv).show();
    });
})
```